# Capture screen as movie with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, video-capture

I want to capture a video of my screen with vb .net, and i'd like to avoid using directx. I found a tutorial here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CaptureScreenAsVideo.aspx but it resulted in the program instantly crashing, i think it was designed for .net 1.1;
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It might be more worthwhile to post a different question to try to fix the crash than start over from scratch.

Comment: Why not use one of many screen to video software packages? There are commercial and open source programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. Just read instruction. Install SDK and Encoder.